# ASP.NET: Generic List in Razor

Tags: c#, asp.net, generics, razor, datagrid

I implemented a generic WebGrid-Class that renders its html-markup according to the specified (row)model.

```
public class WebGrid<TRow> where TRow : WebGridRow{

     public WebGrid(string tableId, IList<TRow> rows){

         // Generate columsn from Model (TRow) by reflection
         ...
     }

     public MvcHtmlString GetHtml(HtmlHelper helper) {
        return new MvcHtmlString(...);
     }

}

public abstract class WebGridRow {
    public virtual string GetRowId() {
        return "row_" + Guid.NewGuid();
    }
}
```

It is possible to define layout, ... with attributes in a model class.
For example:

```
public class MyRowModel : WebGridRow {

    [CanFilter(false)]
    [CssClass("foo")]
    public string Name{get;set;}

    [CanFilter(true)]
    [CssClass("bar")]
    public int SomeOtherProperty{get;set;}

}
```

Now I want to create a generic view, that shows any List of subclasses of WebGridRow as WebGrid. Problem is that Razor does not support generic view models.

Does anyone have an idea how could I solve this?

Comment: What do you mean by "Razor does not support generic view models" ? You can always define the model of the view as WebGrid<YOURMODELTYPE>.

Comment: That is correct. But I cannot define the model as WebGrid<TRow>!

Comment: What is the error ? Because i've used a lot of generics in views. Don't u have a view receiving a model of type ICollection<X> ? Are you sure you are not missing a using in your views (the one containing the WebGrid<X> class) ?

Comment: **Edit** : got it sorry, I missed a line explaining your problem. The problem is in fact that you don't want to define multiple view (depending on the Generic parameter). You can have an interface so that you can define the model of the view as the interface (IWebGrid for example) and then use the interface to expose some fields that can be accessed. Then you could use a DisplayTemplate.

Comment: But again, when using the displaytemplate i face the same problem. I just don't want to implement the listview for each entity itself, but just implement a model and render the grid "genericly".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should help you

**Models**

```
public interface IWebGrid
{
    MvcHtmlString GetHtml(HtmlHelper helper);
}

public class WebGrid<TRow> : IWebGrid where TRow : WebGridRow
{
    private ICollection<TRow> Rows {get;set;}

    public WebGrid(string tableId, IList<TRow> rows)
    {
        // Generate columns from Model (TRow) by reflection and add them to the rows property
    }

    public MvcHtmlString GetHtml(HtmlHelper helper) 
    {
        string returnString = "Generate opening tags for the table itself";
        foreach(TRow row in this.Rows)
        {
            // Generate html for every row
            returnString += row.GetHtml(helper);
        }
        returnString += "Generate closing tags for the table itself";
        return MvcHtmlString.Create(returnString);
    }
}

public abstract class WebGridRow
{
    public virtual string GetRowId() 
    {
        return "row_" + Guid.NewGuid();
    }

    public abstract MvcHtmlString GetHtml(HtmlHelper helper);
}

public class MyRowModel : WebGridRow 
{
    [CanFilter(false)]
    [CssClass("foo")]
    public string Name{get;set;}

    [CanFilter(true)]
    [CssClass("bar")]
    public int SomeOtherProperty{get;set;}

    public override MvcHtmlString GetHtml(HtmlHelper helper)
    {
        // Generate string for the row itself
    }
}
```

**View**
(display template or not)

```
@model IWebGrid
@model.GetHtml(this.Html);
```

Comment: This looks good. But it would mean that the grid is a model, which is definitly false, because the grid is just a control. Or did I understand something wrong?

Comment: Ok, didn't see you wanted to use the DataGrid control. Why do you want a GetHtml() function then if the grid draws itself ? aren't u using it as an object to draw by yourself with your own tags ?

Comment: Yes: Interfaces are the way to go!